# Headphone control in flutter

Tags: flutter

How can I play and pause my audio from headphones in a flutter app? I am using audioplayer plugin for audio playback in my app. It is a basic media player. I tried searching on the web but wasn't able to find much. This was also missing from this player
https://github.com/amangautam1/flutter-musicplayer.
Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: does anyone know any solution?